# Regarding compactness of a space

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, compactness

I am trying to solve the following problem:

Let $X$ be a metrizable topological space. Prove that the following statements are equivalent.

(a) $X$ is compact

(b) $X$ is bounded with respect to every metric on $X$ that induces the topology of $X$.

(c) Every continuous map $f:X\to \mathbb R$ (with the usual metric on $\mathbb R$) is bounded.

My attempt to solve the problem is follows:

(a) implies (b): Let $x\in X$ and let $d$ be a metric which induce the topology on $X$. Then $\{B_r(x):r>0\}$ is an open cover for $X$. Since $X$ is compact, there is a ball with radius $s>0$ such that $X=B_s(x)$. Thus $X$ is bounded.

But I couldn't proceed further. Please help in this regard.

Comment: Some ideas: For a) to b), cover $X$ by finitely-many balls of radius $r$. Then find a bound for the diameter of $X$ from this. For c), the continuousimage of compact is compact in $\mathbb R$ . What are the compact sets in $\mathbb R$?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: for (b) implies (c), suppose that $f:X\to\mathbb R$ is continuous and unbounded. Define $\rho(x,y)=|f(x)-f(y)|+d(x,y)$, where $d$ is the metric on your space. Prove that this is a metric, this metric induces the same topology on $X$, but $(X,\rho)$ is unbounded.

For (c) implies (a), suppose that $X$ is not compact, then there exists a sequence $(x_n)$ that has no convergent subsequence. Prove that the set $A=\{x_n \mathrel{\big\vert} n\in\mathbb N\}$ is closed and all its points are isolated, so every function defined on it is continuous, and use the Tietze extension theorem.

Comment: A has no isolated points or every point of $A$ is isolated?@detnvvp

Comment: I mean that, around every point $p$ of $A$, there exists a ball such that the only point of $A$ it contains is $p$.

Comment: yeah, that means if I understood correctly, every point of $A$ is an isolated point of $A$. Isn't it?

Comment: Yes, the way you say it.

Comment: But Tietze extension theorem is valied for bounded functions only. So, if I want to construct an unbounded continuous function from $A$ to $\mathbb R$, how Tietze extension theorem will be used?

Comment: There is no need for $f$ to be bounded; you can refer to the general theorem that applies to topological spaces, eg here: http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Tietze_Extension_Theorem .

Comment: Yes, got it finally. Thanks!